# What URL should I use for monitoring the availability of Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm setting up monitoring of my magento installation and was curious if there's a particular URL / action that I should use for the monitor.

At the moment I'm using `/admin/`--it's a small, quick, and responds to the maintenance flag.  That makes it meet my criteria, but I was wondering if there is a better option.

Comment: Seams ok to me to use the admin login page. Just one comment. You may want to change the  admin route from `admin` to something else, so other people won't know it.

Comment: Are you just trying to monitor if your site is reachable or do you also want to check if the page is fully loaded?
Admin URL seems also ok for me for the first reason but I think it would make sense to check the main website URL as some implementations/extensions can cause errors on your website.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I'm just looking for basic reachability for now for checking availability and for offlining a given server from a load-balanced pool.  Some systems I've worked with have a dedicated call for this purpose, so I thought I'd ask.  The admin page is working very well for me at the moment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with all the comments and suggest that `admin` would be a good fit for this need as it should always accessible unless something has gone seriously wrong, which I guess would be what you are looking for.